# Language dimension in Neos is not working

Tags: neoscms

This is my Settings.yaml located at MyPackage/Configuration/Settings.yaml

```
TYPO3:
  TYPO3CR:
    contentDimensions:
      language:
        default: 'de'
        defaultPreset: 'de'
        presets:
          'all': ~
          'de':
            label: 'de'
            values: ['de', 'en_UK', 'en_US']
            uriSegment: 'de'
          'en_US':
            label: 'en'
            values: ['en_US']
            uriSegment: 'en'
```

This is the error message when i try to put that code in:

> Uncaught exception #1415880445 in line 54 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asummerstale\neos\Data\Temporary\Development\Cache\Code\Flow_Object_Classes\TYPO3_Neos_TypoScript_DimensionMenuImplementation.php: Dimension "language" was referenced, but not configured.

Full stack trace: http://pastie.org/9958883

And  i cannot access anypage with that code in.

I'm using this reference http://neos.readthedocs.org/en/1.2/IntegratorsCookbook/TranslatingContent.html

Answer (score 0):

Found it, just migrate the migration node flow node:migrate 20140326143834 and flow node:repair.